# disable a specific link on ios uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How can I disable a specific link on iOS uiwebview ? 
The page loaded in the webview can have thousand urls but i want to disable one url.

I am sensing  i have to use this method for the work. But can't figure it out.

```
 func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with objective-c. Sorry if my swift code is wrong. I hope you understand with the logic.

Try it.

```
 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

   let surl = request.url?.absoluteString

   if surl == "http://disableurl.com" {
      return false;
   }      
   return true;
 }
```